# Hue distinct users in rolling 7 day count

Tags: hive, hiveql, hue

I've spent 3 days researching this and trying to figure it out but with no luck. Right now I'm considering just loading the data into a new table one day at a time (would take too long and really don't want to do this).

I have a table with pageviews for a website in it. It's located in a Hive table and I access the data with Hue. It has distinct user ID, session ID, date and page. We get about 16 million views per day  over about 30 different pages.

I'm trying to create a page view count, distinct user count and 7 day rolling distinct user count. So distinct users in a day and distinct users for the week leading up to that day. examples below.

I've tried to use a partition by statement but with no luck. I've tried to join the table to itself as well as joining it to a date_dimension table, but with a table of 16M rows per day Hue ends up hanging and never completing the query

Here is the code I have for just one day, but I need to expand this to be the entire last year instead of inputting data into a new table one day at a time. Obviously need to replace hard-coded dates.

```
SELECT '2019-04-07' AS Temp_Date
    , t.pageview
    , COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN t.dates = '2019-04-07' THEN User_ID END) AS Users
    , COUNT (DISTINCT User_ID) AS 7Day_Users
    , COUNT (CASE WHEN t.dates = '2019-04-07' THEN User_ID END) AS Views
    , COUNT (*) AS 7Day_Views
FROM(

SELECT pageview
    , User_ID
    , Date

FROM ar3.t59_4_1 

WHERE Date BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-07'
) t
GROUP BY '2019-04-07'
    ,t.pageview
```

Example Results table for current code:

```
Temp_Date  pageview  Users  7Day_users  Views  7Day_views
2019-04-07  Home     5467     28754      8765   51624
2019-04-07  About    150      548        324    3429
2019-04-07  Store    26345    128754     33247  354324
2019-04-07  Blog     856      28754      8765   54324
2019-04-07  FAQ      32       187        65     478
```

Actual results are much longer. Expected outcome is to have this for every day.

```
Temp_Date  pageview  Users  7Day_users  Views  7Day_views
2019-04-07  Home     5467     28754      8765   51624
2019-04-07  About    150      548        324    3429
2019-04-07  Store    26345    128754     33247  354324
2019-04-07  Blog     856      28754      8765   54324
2019-04-07  FAQ      32       187        65     478
2019-04-06  Home     5467     28754      8765   51624
2019-04-06  About    150      548        324    3429
2019-04-06  Store    26345    128754     33247  354324
2019-04-06  Blog     856      28754      8765   54324
2019-04-06  FAQ      32       187        65     478
2019-04-05  Home     5467     28754      8765   51624
2019-04-05  About    150      548        324    3429
2019-04-05  Store    26345    128754     33247  354324
2019-04-05  Blog     856      28754      8765   54324
2019-04-05  FAQ      32       187        65     478
2019-04-04  Home     5467     28754      8765   51624
2019-04-04  About    150      548        324    3429
2019-04-04  Store    26345    128754     33247  354324
2019-04-04  Blog     856      28754      8765   54324
2019-04-04  FAQ      32       187        65     478
...etc. (continues for all days in past 12 months)
```

Comment: Did you consider to make a ETL (process) that will run your first query every day and populate a final table that will look like your last query?